# Avoid unboxing for vectors with 1 value

Tags: r, jsonlite, unboxing

For an API I wish to push data to, I need to avoid unboxing to happen on specific values.

Consider the following input:

```
library(jsonlite)

lsA <- list(propertyName = "listA",
            Values = c("x"))

lsB <- list(propertyName = "listB",
            Values = c("a","b","c"))

lsC <- list(propertyName = "listC",
            min = 1,
            max = 3)
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "listA",
    "Values": ["x"]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "listB",
    "Values": ["a", "b", "c"]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "listC",
    "min": 1,
    "max": 3
  }
]
```

However, when I do this:

```
lsTest <- list()
lsTest <- list.append(lsTest,I(lsA),lsB,lsC)

jsonTest <- jsonlite::toJSON(lsTest,auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
jsonTest
```

I'm getting this (notice the unboxed value for listA):

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "listA",
    "Values": "x"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "listB",
    "Values": ["a", "b", "c"]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "listC",
    "min": 1,
    "max": 3
  }
]
```

How can I avoid specific one-element vectors to be unboxed during the toJSON conversion?

**EDIT**: cwthom kindly resolved it. Just change `c("x")` to `list("x")`. It works for lists with multiple items as well, and only add some additional new lines, which appear to be cosmetics only and did not have any negative impact on the end result on my end.

Comment: Just a guess, but try `values = list("x")`, rather than using `c`?

Comment: This works, but doesn't seem to be a generic solution. Applying the same on the "lsB" gives the wrong result. I guess there must be a more generic approach to this. I'll hold this as my backup though.

Comment: Does it give the wrong result for `lsB` ? `list("a", "b", "c")` turns into `["a", "b", "c"]` for me (with some extra linebreaks from `pretty = TRUE`.)

Comment: It is indeed working except for the linebreaks (which I thought would give an issue, yet they don't). Thanks. This solves it!